# "Consul connect Envoy" cannot reach service

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, consul, envoyproxy, servicemesh

I have a MariaDB database installed directly on a host and a Nomad cluster hosting a phpMyAdmin. Both hosts are inside the same Consul cluster.

I'm having some issues trying to connect the phpMyAdmin to my database.
phpMyAdmin returns the error:

> mysqli::real_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=26

Here's the config file for the phpMyAdmin job

```
job "pma" {
  datacenters = ["nomeau"]
  region      = "OVH"
  type        = "service"
  
  group "pma"{
    count = 1

    network {
      mode = "bridge"

      port "http" {
        static = 8083
        to = 80
      }
    }
    service {
      name =  "pma" 
      port = "http"
      connect {
        sidecar_task {
          config {
            #Have to st privileged true to avoid crashes and error 
            #su: cannot set groups: Operation not permitted at envoy setup
            privileged = true 
            args = [
              "-c",
              "${NOMAD_SECRETS_DIR}/envoy_bootstrap.json",
              "-l",
              "debug",
              "--concurrency",
              "${meta.connect.proxy_concurrency}",
              "--disable-hot-restart"
            ]
          }
        }
        sidecar_service {
          proxy {
            upstreams {
              destination_name = "bdd"
              local_bind_port  = 3306
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
    task "phpMyAdmin" {
      driver = "docker"
      env = {
        PMA_HOST = "127.0.0.1"
      }

      config {
        image = "phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest"
        ports = ["http"]
        privileged = true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the bdd.hcl defining the database's service

```
service {
  name = "bdd"
  id = "bdd"
  port = 3006

  connect {
    sidecar_service {}
  }
}
```

To start the envoy sidecar for the database, I used the following command
`consul connect envoy -sidecar-for bdd -- -l debug --log-path logs/envoy.log`

And you'll find the envoy logs from the database sidecar proxy on gist [here](https://gist.github.com/KyabeSamaEPSI/bf9474285722a3ca57c5c9d39610a589).

I think I'm just missing a simple config option but I have no idea which one.

Answer (score 0):

So,
I fixed the issue.

It was a simple type in bdd.hcl. I wrote 3006 instead of 3306 for the port